# Read csv adds \t to each column and value

Tags: python

When i read my csv

```js
cs = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

it adds a \t to each column and value except of numbers (so to all strings)
I downloaded the file from the same source where i have downloaded previous files and there it didn't add it. I have the same reading command as always

```js
     \tamplitude_id       \tuser_id \tcity \tcountry  ...                                   \tgp:utm_content \tgp:utm_medium \tgp:utm_source               \tgp:utm_term
0      123456789    123456789     \t        \t  ...                                                 \t              \t              \t                          \t
1      123456789  123456789     \t        \t  ...                                                 \t              \tpaid                \t                          \t
```

how can I read it without the \t

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: how can i read it without the \t
as this is added when reading and not in the original file

Comment: Are you sure there are no tab characters in the input file? Maybe tab is the column separator

Answer (score 5):

When you see `"\t"` after reading a file it represents `tab` and in CSV it usually represents a different column in the same row

so adding `sep = '\t'` to your original command should do the trick:

```
cs = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv',sep = '\t' ,encoding='utf-8')
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: unfortunatley sep = ' \t' doesn't solve the problem for me 
is there a possibility to check if there is a column in a row with code ? so that i can get rid of it ?

Comment: what exactly seems to be the problem? do you still get cols with "\t" ?

Comment: yes exactly 
it looks the same no matter if I add sep='\t' or not.
How do I check if I have a tab in the column ?